# Insert into mysql date time and datetime only by adding date and time

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I have the following problem:

```
$date = $_POST["date"];

$time = $_POST["time"];

$date $time = $_POST["datetime"];
```

or

```
$datetime = "$date $time";

$datetime = $_POST["datetime"];
```

how does it works that i can insert into 3 rows?

Comment: Something like $datetime = $date.$time; ?

Comment: could you add some example what are you trying to do?

Comment: simply in database your field must be datetime type and at insertion time you should use NOW() function simply it insert date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Make use of the concatenate operator **`.`** to achieve this.

```
$date = $_POST["date"];
$time = $_POST["time"];
$datetime = $date.$time; // Your date and time is concatenated into $datetime variable.
```